# Callback interface to a functional interface

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, anonymous-inner-class

I am trying to become familiar with Java 8's Functional Interfaces for obvious reasons. I slowly understanding the concept and have been trying to refactor some existing code to use it. I'm sure there is a few different approaches to implement this... However for what ever reason, I am struggling - and it's really frustrating. Perhaps it doesn't make sense to use it here but I will let you be the judge...

My current callback implementation uses an anonymous inner class that I would (hopefully) replace with a lambda expression. Here is an example:

**MessageReceived.java**

```
public class MessageReceived {
    private final Map<String, Researcher> researchers = new HashMap<>();

    public void receive(String researcherName, ResearchData researchData) {
        if (!researchers.containsKey(researcherName)) {

            researchers.put(researcherName, new Researcher(new ResearchCallback() {
                @Override
                public void discoveredResearch(ResearchData researchData, Map<Object, String> discovered) {

                    // iterate discovered
                    discovered.forEach((object, stringData) -> {
                        // do something
                    });
                }
            }));
        }

        researchers.get(researcherName).research(researchData);
    }
}
```

**ResearcherCallback.java**

```
public interface ResearcherCallback {

    void discoveredResearch(ResearchData data, Map<Object, String> discovered);
}
```

**Researcher.java**

```
public class Researcher {
    private final ResearchCallback callback;

    public Researcher(ResearchCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void research(ResearchData data) {
        // quite a bit of logic goes here that builds the list of data...
        callback.discoveredResearch(data, mapOfDiscoveredStuff);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your lambda would look like `(event, map) -> {..}`. But I can't find any object of type `Event` in `receive` method. Also what is `discovered`?

Comment: Updated. `discovered` is a map containing objects that `research()` method found. It is returned back to the callback interface where the AIC `discoveredResearch` in `MessageReceived.java` is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your anonymous class by the lambda body that corresponds to the functional interface `ResearchCallback`.

The method of your interface functional is :

```
void discoveredResearch(ResearchData data, Map<Object, String> discovered);
```

It accepts two params and returns nothing.
So a lambda body such as `(data, discovered) -> {}` suits to.

It would give :

```
researchers.put(researcherName, new Researcher( (data, discovered) ->
        discovered.forEach((object, stringData) -> {
            // do something
        }));
);
```